# How to convert this date to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I need to convert such date in format string 2019-08-02T07:00:00+0000
to a datetime.

I've tried like this:

```py
date_1 = dt.datetime.strptime(date_1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M+0000")
```

and like this:

```
date_1 = dt.datetime.strptime(date_1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%SZ")
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about the seconds, you need

```
dt.datetime.strptime(date_1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")
```

You can debug stuff like this easily by successively removing parts from `date_1` as well as your format string:

```
dt.datetime.strptime("2019-08-02T07:00:00+0000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M+0000")
#error
dt.datetime.strptime("2019-08-02T07:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
#unconverted data remains: :00
dt.datetime.strptime("T07:00:00", "T%H:%M")
#unconverted data remains: :00
dt.datetime.strptime("07:00:00", "%H:%M")
#now it should be obvious
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
date_object = datetime.date.today()
print(date_object)
```